# Express.js Query Based on URL Parameter?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I want to get the data from my MongoDB database depending on the URL . If I access localhost:3000/phones it should get all the data with the category phones, where if it is localhost:3000/laptops it should get all the laptops.

Below is my schema:

```
    name: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
    category: {
        required: true,
        type: String
    },
```

Below is how my current version:

```
router.get('/getAll', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await Model.find();
        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

I tried to `findByID` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer could be very well found in its documentation at :- https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/quick-reference/

```
router.get('/phones', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await Model.find({category: "phones"});
        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

As the same query is used for phone and laptop requests you can refactor it
to handle in the same endpoint by using query parameters in the request

url will be of format:- localhost:3000/getAll?category=phones

```
router.get('/getAll', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const category = req.query.category
        const data = await Model.find({category: category});
        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you should send your request with query param ?category=phones or ?category=laptops

so then you can get your category from `req.query.category`.

that is what you're looking for:

```
router.get('/getAll', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const category = req.query.category;

        const data = await Model.find({
            category,
        });

        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

Comment: I made the route string empty instead of "/getAll" . The url works  localhost:3000/?category=phones . I added another field to the schema called sub_category . Each item now has a subcategory e.g (name=iphone11,category=phone,sub_category=iphone) . I understand that i must use the URL localhost:3000/category=phones&sub_category=iphone to get all iphones . However how would i set the router to be able to display this once i use this URL .

Comment: simply repeat all steps as u did to get search by category work